# Quantile function in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm new to Stata and didn't find the answer in the help, navigating the menus, or online so far. I would just like to know how to access the quantile function of a distribution. For example in R, if I want to know the 0.95 point of the $\chi^2(1)$ distribution, I do:

```
> qchisq(0.95,1)
[1] 3.841459
```

Is there an equivalent command in Stata ?

Comment: `di invchi2(1,0.95)`. Type `help density_functions` for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding syntax in Stata is to use a function:

```
di invchi2(1, 0.95)
```

Type `help density_functions` for more information.

PS: FYI, this question is very likely to be off-topic here on SE.

Comment: @RobertLong You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata